# how can I read the movie settings in AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I need to use the movie's predefined framerate (not it's real time performance FPS, but just the number it was designated to run at) as well as the movie's width and height, using AS2.  Is this possible? I can't seem to find what object I should be examining for this information.

[EDIT] I see that Stage has width and height but nothing about frame rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read or set the stage FPS in AS2, you'll need to go AS3 for that.

If you only need an approximate of the FPS you can calculate the FPS over a time period, where you're making sure the swf isn't doing anything else.
This will give a good estimate, because Flash will not exceed your given FPS by a lot (+-2 or 3 FPS).